# Checking if ip with port is available?

Tags: c#, ip, port

I need to know how to check if an IP with Port is working to connect to.
Port is 7171, and I'm using Visual Studio C# Express 2010 .NET.

Comment: tried Google? here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Have you tried just opening a connection?

Comment: @mtijn, ping doesn't work with specific ports, just IP addresses.

Comment: Telnet is what i use to check port specific stuff

Comment: use portquery to check post status. Ex: portqry -n ip address -e port number

Comment: @svick: Im hosting a server and want to restart it when connection lost xd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check ip is working you can do a ping using your code and opening cmd from your code.

You can check if port is free assuming you are using tcpclint :

```
int port = 456; //<--- This is your value
bool isAvailable = true;

IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
 TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

 foreach (TcpConnectionInformation tcpi in tcpConnInfoArray)
 {
   if (tcpi.LocalEndPoint.Port==port)
   {
     isAvailable = false;
     break;
   }
 }
```